# Why am I getting the process error 0xc0000005 with my code in C

Tags: c

This project is the skyline project for a school work, and at the moment I'm getting an error when I'm putting in the coordinates being that this error is 0xc0000005.
Everything else is running smoothly as for now if I'm not wrong.
If someone could explain to me why this is happening I would be grateful.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int registerednumber; // It registers the number of buildings used in the array of buildings;
} registernumber;

typedef struct
{
    int li;//POINT MOST TO THE LEFT
    int hi;//HEIGHT OF THE BUILDING
    int ri;//POINT MOST TO THE RIGHT
} buildings;

void exitprogram(){
    exit(0);
}

int menu() {
    int optioninmenu=0;
    do {
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("-------------SKYLINES------------- \n");
        printf(" 1-REGISTER NUMBER OF BUILDINGS \n");
        printf(" 2-REGISTER BUILDING COORDINATES \n");
        printf(" 3-EXECUTE SKYLINE \n");
        printf(" 4-CREDITS \n");
        printf(" 5-EXIT \n \n");
        printf(" TYPE YOUR OPTION: ");
        scanf("%d", &optioninmenu);
    } while(optioninmenu!= 1 && optioninmenu!= 2 && optioninmenu!= 3 && optioninmenu!= 4 && optioninmenu!= 5 && optioninmenu!=0);
    return(optioninmenu);
}

int credits() {
    int returntomenu = 0;
    system("cls");
    printf(" ################################ \n");
    printf(" #This program was done by:     #\n");
    printf(" #Joao Moura A93099             #\n");
    printf(" #Eva Castro A93097             # \n");
    printf(" ################################ \n \n");
    printf("\n TYPE ENTER TO RETURN TO THE MAIN MENU");
    getchar();
    return menu();
}

int countbuildings(buildings *building, int *regnumberofbuildings) {
    int returntomenu = 0;
    int i=0;
    int numberofbuildings=0;
    system("cls");
    printf(" TYPE IN THE NUMBER OF BUILDINGS: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberofbuildings);
    *regnumberofbuildings=numberofbuildings;
    printf("%d",*regnumberofbuildings);
    printf("\n TYPE ENTER TO RETURN TO THE MAIN MENU");
    getchar();
    return menu();
}

int coordinates(buildings *building,int regnumberofbuildings) {
    int i=0;
    building=(buildings *)malloc(regnumberofbuildings*sizeof(building));
    system("cls");
    printf("%d",regnumberofbuildings);
    for(i=0;i!=regnumberofbuildings;i++){
        system("cls");
        printf("Building number %d \n \n", i+1);
        printf(" TYPE THE LEFTMOST COORDINATE: ");
        scanf("%d", &building[i].li);
        printf("\n TYPE IN THE HEIGHT OF THE BUILDING: ");
        scanf("%d", &building[i].hi);
        printf("\n TYPE THE RIGHTMOST COORDINATE: ");
        scanf("%d", &building[i].ri);
    }
    printf("\n TYPE ENTER TO RETURN TO THE MAIN MENU");
    getchar();
    return menu();
}

int main()
{
    int numberofbuildings=0;
    int registerednumber=0;
    buildings *building;
    int option=0;
    int i=0;
    do{
        option=menu();
        if(option==1){
            countbuildings(building,&numberofbuildings);
        }
        if(option==2){
            coordinates(building,numberofbuildings);
            getchar();
        }
        if(option==4){
            credits();
        }
    }while(option!=5);
    if(option==5){
        printf("Thanks for using our program!");
        printf("Press enter to leave the program");
        getchar();
        exitprogram();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in function coordinates you are using building variable as a local one so your external variable is not getting assigned. Your definition should be int coordinates(buildings **building,int regnumberofbuildings) and you should call it coordinates(&building,numberofbuildings); You can make local temporary variable and work with it and then assign it to the reference you should pass into the function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Using functions with variadic parameter list without providing the prototype is a bad idea. For `printf` you should include `stdio.h`. And your compiler should raise some warning about using functions without prototype (implicit declaration...). Therefore you should enable all warnings.

Comment: In that school project you should learn latest C standards. Empty parameter lists are deprecated and should not be used for new code.

Comment: sizeof(building) == sizeof(void*). you are allocating wrong number of bytes. it should be malloc(regnumberofbuildings*sizeof(building**s**));

Comment: Besides the previous comments you should read [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then modify your code to be a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with emphasis on **minimal**, i.e. remove all the code that is not needed to reproduce your problem. For example all those tons of prints are not required to demonstrate the issue. This will make it easier for everyone to read it and as a positive side effect you might already find your problem during that process.